# Ricoh C5503 folds booklets backwards

Tags: printing, printer

Every time I print a booklet using the Ricoh C5503 printer at work, the booklet finisher folds the pages backwards (inside out).  Everything is in the right order, except I have to turn the fold the other direction -- the cover or first page is the innermost, and what should be the center is on the outside.

How can I get the booklet finisher to fold the pages in the opposite direction?

Edit for clarification: This is a saddle-stitch booklet using the options in the printer driver to do so.  I am *not* using the application settings in my browser or PDF reader to create the booklet, I'm using the printer driver to do it directly so it will staple for me.

Edit for solution: Turns out it was the driver, which was provided by the network print server and was several years old. Updating to a new driver using a local LAN connection resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the printer receives the pages in reverse order. Can you find a setting in the app/driver that controls that?

My PDF viewer (PDF-XChange Editor) has a "Reverse order" button in the print dialogue box. Acrobat Reader DC does as well, but it's hidden under More Options.

Comment: No, that's not it. I tried reversing the page order and it printed what seemed like an almost random page order (until I folded *that* inside out, and then it was a booklet in reverse-page order).  It's not the semantic "pages" that are ordered wrong, it's the physical pieces of paper generated by the printer. It's folding them back to front instead of front to back.

Comment: It sounds weird that the hardware can fold them the wrong way. Have you contacted Ricoh support?